# Sum of Factorials from a to b in scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a function in scala that finds the `Sum of any (passed) function from a to b`. Additionally , I'm trying to do it in a tail-wise recursive manner. I managed a tailwise recursive factorial function , so now i want to pass it to the "Summation" function and have it find the sum of all factorials from lower-bound `a` to upper-bound `b` .  Here's what i have so far

```
object Sum {
  def Summation( f : Double => Double , a: Double , b: Double):Double = {
    def tailwiseSummation(accumulator:Double , count:Double):Double = {
      if(count > b) accumulator
      else tailwiseSummation(accumulator + f, a+1) // i dont know what to do here
    } 
  }

  def Factorial(num: Double): Double = { // i want to pass this function to `Summation`
    def tailwise(accumulator: Double, deprecator: Double): Double = {
      if (deprecator == 0) accumulator
      else tailwise(accumulator * deprecator, deprecator - 1) // deprecator deprecating 1 unit at a time
    }
    tailwise(1, num)
  }
}
```

can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. Call `f` with `count` and add 1 to `count` in the recursive call `tailwiseSummation`. Also, you need the initialization function `tailwiseSummation(f(a), a + 1)` just like `Factorial`.

```
object Sum {
  def Summation( f : Double => Double , a: Double , b: Double):Double = {
    def tailwiseSummation(accumulator:Double , count:Double):Double = {
      if(count > b) accumulator
      else tailwiseSummation(accumulator + f(count), count+1)
    } 
    // accumulator starts with f(a) , so count starts from a+1 to remove off-by-one error        
    tailwiseSummation(f(a), a + 1) 
  }

  def Factorial(num: Double): Double = { 
    def tailwise(accumulator: Double, deprecator: Double): Double = {
      if (deprecator == 0) accumulator
      else tailwise(accumulator * deprecator, deprecator - 1) // deprecator deprecating 1 unit at a time
    }
    tailwise(1, num)
  }
}
```

Run it:

```
scala> Sum.Summation(Sum.Factorial(_), 1, 5)
res0: Double = 153.0
```

Comment: @SomjitNag Not quite. Note the difference between the initialization call and the recursive call to `tailwiseSummation`. `a + 1` in the initialization call increases `a` since you already evaluated `f(a)` and don't need to do it again. `count + 1` in the recursive call counts out the range. It's not an infinite loop.

Comment: @SomjitNag It's an off by one error. See my previous comment.

Comment: i was looking in the wrong place , count+1 is right , but the off by one error imo makes the code feel non-intuitive. i would have liked it to be more elegant.

Comment: added a line of comment to make things easier to read and understand

Answer (score 1):

Generic recursion over the range could be something like that :

```
def makeSum(f: Double => Double, a:Double, b:Double, step:Double = 1.0):Double = {
  def makeSumAcc(f:Double =>Double, a:Double, b:Double, acc:Double) = {
    if (a>=b) acc
    else makeSumAcc(f, a+step, b, acc+f(a))
  }
  makeSum(f, a, b, 0)
}
```

Comment: can you explain the meaning of `f: Double => Double` , i'm learning from an online course, i suppose this means call by name , but i'm not quite sure. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: `f: Double => Double` is a function that takes a `Double` and returns a `Double`. e.g. your `Factorial` function.

Comment: in here `makeSum(f: Double => Double,...` no arguments are specified for f , but i can write `f(a)` later in the code , how does that work ?

Comment: f is a function signature. It gets one argument, Double,  and returns a Double result. Any function with the same signature can be passed here. Later we use it with a Double parameter.